# WebService caching active?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I wrote my first WebService.

My System is ISS7, ASP.Net, Framework 3.5.

My code only gives a "Hello World" back and all settings are correct, so I can return in IE the "Hello World".

Now when I Change my Text from "Hello World" to "Good Bye World" and copy the file in the webservice folder, nothing changed in the IE. It's the old text the whole time.

What is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues is more likely IE caching. Have you tried CTRL+F5 to refresh your page?

The other issue could be the method of deployment, when you change your code, its possible its not being deployed to your webserver.